# how to display datetime arraylist in textboxfor in table Partial view mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, model-view-controller, razor-pages

i have arraylist  contains id,datetime and boolen(Chechbox)
when it binds in table only datetime doesn't binds in write way if it binds in textboxfor(i need to make date editable) it binds correct in labels

```
    <tbody id="employeeScheduleList">
    @if (Model != null && Model.R != null && Model.R.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in Model.R)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @if (@file.ReceivingDateValue != null)
                        {
                            @file.ReceivingDateValue.Value.ToShortDateString()
                        }
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_" })
                        @if (file.ReceivingDateValue != null)
                        {
                            <script>
                                var t = document.getElementById("ReceivingDate_");
                                  t.value = '@file.ReceivingDateValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
                            </script>
                        }
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => file.ReceivingDateValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

My Issue in issue in `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_" })` as the value of ReceivingDateValue is binds correctly and when i insbect it in chrome  i found the write value but it textbox shows wrong value 
I want to view date in textbox to make it editable

Comment: Try adding the value to the helper tag as one of the attributes:                                             `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => file.FileIDValue, new { @class = "form-control hidden EMPF", value = File.FileIDValue }`

Comment: issue in `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_" })` the value is binds correctly

Comment: Then try @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_", value = File.ReceivingDate  })

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression `x=> file.FileIDValue` is binding the value from the client to the controller. Adding the value as an attribute should bind from the server to the client and provide the results you're looking for

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => file.FileIDValue, new { @class = "form-control hidden EMPF", value = File.FileIDValue }
```

Comment: My  issue in `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_" })` as the value of ReceivingDateValue is binds correctly and when i insbect it in chrome i found the write value but it textbox shows wrong value I want to view date in textbox to make it editable